# Why Bootstrap 4 columns are not showing

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have added Bootstrap row with columns.

```html
div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But there are rows, not columns.
Could you please advise, what I should correct?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have loaded the Bootstrap 3 CSS file but you're using Bootstrap 4 column classes. Here are the docs for the Bootstrap 3 grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: Which bootstrap did you load? Show us the stylesheet link...

Comment: Also - don't game the system by stuffing words into your title to force it to allow your question.  Make your question title more accurate / specific, but don't stuff "underscore.me" which adds *nothing* to the question.

Comment: All worked! Thank you for your help!